# FlatList rerenders data from Firebase multiple times whenever new data is added

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am attempting to build a chat app interface using react native and firebase and am having problems updating the data that is fetched from my database.  I can load existing data into the Flatlist I am using fine:

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebaseApp.database();
let ref = db.ref("/room");

 componentDidMount() {
      ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot){
          childData.push(childSnapshot.val());
        });
        this.setState({
          messages: childData
        });
       messageCount = snapshot.numChildren();
     }.bind(this));
 }
```

Flatlist Code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <FlatList
          data={this.state.messages}
          // renderItem={({item}) =><Text>{item.contents}</Text>}
          keyExtractor = {item => item.timestamp}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Bubble style={{margin: 10}} 
          color="#FFC800" arrowPosition='right'>{item.contents}</Bubble>}
            />}
        />
        <Button onPress={()=>{this.onPressButton()}} title="Send">Click me</Button>      
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This is where I add the text in a text input to the database

```
function addMessage(messageText) {
  messageCount++;
  firebase.database().ref('room/'+messageCount).set({
      contents: messageText,
      timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  });
}
```

That code gives me the following result which is what I want (ignore the terrible styling):
[image]

But whenever I try to send a message, it gets added to the database correctly, but the flatlist updates to show this:

[image]

Where the previous message and the new message are rendered multiple times. What is the best way to render a new item from the database into the flatlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I couldn't find where you are initializing your `childData`.

Assuming that your database is correct, then it looks like you are not cleaning `childData` before assigning it to your state here

```
this.setState({
  messages: childData
});
```

So when your code run this push `childData.push(childSnapshot.val());` it adds to your array all the new content and keeps the old one.

Example:

First state:

```
// snapshot.val() contains ['Hello']
childData = ['Hello']
```

Submited text: `World!`

Updated state:

```
// snapshot.val() contains ['Hello', 'World']
childData = ['Hello', 'Hello', 'World!']
```

A suggestion to solve this would be to assign the array only with the new value, so instead of using `push`, you could do something like this `childData = snapshot.val()`

I also suggest you to debug your code with some `console.log` in order to understand what is being retrived by `snapshot.val()` or `childData`, or `this.state.messages`

Hope it helps

Edit:
Reading again, a possible problem could also be that since JS is sync, your `setState` is being called before your `forEach` is finished. A solution could be using `async/await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Something like this:

```
ref.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
  const childData = await snapshot.map((childSnapshot) => {
   childSnapshot.val();
  });
  this.setState({
    messages: childData
  });
 (...)
```

Consider the code above just as an example

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the input. I'll attempt to implement your suggestions tomorrow and I'll let you know if I can get it working.

Comment: I got it working, all I had to do was reinitialize the child data array at the beginning of the first function in ref.on.  Here is the updated working code:                                                                     
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        childData = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot){
          childData.push(childSnapshot.val())
        });